# Plug into viewDidLoad() in protocol

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I would like to write a protocol that I can use in all modal presented `UIViewController`. The goal of the protocol is to, for example, automatically add a close button as the `rightBarButtonItem`. by doing the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ModalController {
}
```

What's the best way to achieve such a thing?

Comment: You could do this just by subclassing `UIViewController`. Protocols are not necessary, but are of course an option.

Comment: Subclassing wouldn't be the most beautiful option, since some of these viewcontrollers subclass from different classes. So I'd have to create a special Modal instance of all the "parent" classes.

Comment: Ok sure. I’ll have a think! :)

Answer (score 1):

How would a protocol automatically do sth? Protocols enforce existence of certain functions, variables and can offer default implementations as well as extended functionality that can be called.

That is why deriving from UIViewController makes more sense.

Another option is to create a container ViewController. A ModalViewController as a container which embeds a given UIViewController inside. This way you could make space for the back button.

ViewController composition is not so bad once you worked through several tutorials and got some code to make it simple. ViewController composition in general can make coding ViewControllers beautiful ;). Its the only way to avoid massively bloated ViewControllers so a good skill to learn if you are in for the long game.

[Tutorial on ViewController composition.](https://medium.com/@johnsundell/using-child-view-controllers-as-plugins-in-swift-458e6b277b54)